# How to import allowed values lists into Drupal 8?

Tags: entities, 8

I have a Drupal 6 site, with some fields that allow you to pick from a list of allowed values. These values are then stored/linked to the node/entity. After migrating from the old site, these values are still stored/linked to the node/entity, but the field itself does not have a list of allowed values. So if I edit a node that has this field, I can't pick anything from the list.

I can re-create the list of values (which get keys automatically generated to be the same as the values) but that seems like the wrong thing to do. Does anyone know how I can simply migrate the existing list into Drupal 8 properly, or where these key/value pairs are stored so I can just create some SQL scripts to populate them instead?

Comment: Migrate supports importing CCK allowed_values. Perhaps the migration did not run or you can look at and share your site logs to see why? I think the migrate manifest name for it is `d6_field_settings`.

Comment: Sounds like you found a migrate bug. You should create a bug report, and figure out how to fix it. Try the #drupal-migrate IRC channel after creating your issue and then ask there for help on how to fix it.

Comment: Cross-linking here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2667206

Comment: @mradcliffe I used drush to perform the migration, and I didn't see any errors in the output... When you talk about the `d6_field_settings` do you mean I should look at the config that is exported before the migrations are run? I'm not a Drupal developer (I'm a python/C# developer) so you might have to explain where things live in Drupal-land.